# Why Mockito.mock() fails to mock a class with Hystrix annotations?

Tags: java, spring, mockito

I've got a Spring Boot 2 project with the following dependencies

```
com.netflix.hystrix:hystrix-core:1.5.18

org.mockito:mockito-core:2.23.4
```

And the following service

```
@Service
public class CardsProvider {
    @HystrixCommand(groupKey = "CARDS")
    public Observable<List<Card>> getCards(UserData userData, String cus) {
        ...
    }
}
```

I am trying to mock this class in my test configuration

```
@Bean
@Primary
public CardsProvider cardsProvider() {
    return Mockito.mock(CardsProvider.class);
}
```

Unfortunately, this error is thrown:

org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class com.company.api.accounts.services.CardsProvider$MockitoMock$1544042825: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is org.springframework.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
**Caused by: org.springframework.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError--
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/company/api/accounts/services/CardsProvider$MockitoMock$1544042825**

Without `@HystrixCommand` annotation everything is fine.How can I solve this?

Comment: Why are you mixing Mockito with Spring tests? Either use Mockito or Spring mocks like `@SpyBean` or `@MockBean`. Also show what runner you are using to launch your tests.

Comment: And obviously the error says everything - Spring is trying to create a proxy bean for your bean created with Mockito and it fails.

Comment: There was no problems with it before moving to Spring Boot 2

Comment: @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {Application.class, TestConfiguration.class, TestHazelcastConfiguration.class},
        value = "spring.cloud.consul.enabled=false", webEnvironment = RANDOM_PORT)